# Atom feed (XML) parsing in python

Tags: python, xml, atom-feed

In my python program, i make a rest call and i get the following output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This is to override browser formatting; see server.conf[httpServer] to disable. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xml" href="/static/atom.xsl"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:s="http://dev.myweb.com/ns/rest" xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
  <title>ABC</title>
  <id>123ABC</id>
  <updated>2013-09-05T12:34:51+05:30</updated>
  <author>
    <name>itsme</name>
  </author>
  <s:messages/>
  <entry>
    <title>ABC1</title>
    <id>123ABC123/id>
    <updated>2013-09-05T12:34:51+05:30</updated>
    <author>
      <name>itsyou</name>
    </author>
    <content type="text/xml">
      <s:dict>
        <s:key name="creation_time">1372890070</s:key>
        <s:key name="A:a"><s:dict><s:key name="app"></s:key><s:key name="can_list">1</s:key><s:key name="can_write">1</s:key><s:key name="modifiable">0</s:key><s:key name="owner">itsyou</s:key><s:key name="perms"><s:dict><s:key name="read"><s:list><s:item>admin</s:item></s:list></s:key><s:key name="write"><s:list><s:item>admin</s:item></s:list></s:key></s:dict></s:key><s:key name="removable">0</s:key><s:key name="sharing">system</s:key></s:dict></s:key>
        <s:key name="expiration_time">1404426070</s:key>
        <s:key name="features"><s:list><s:item>A</s:item><s:item>B</s:item><s:item>C</s:item><s:item>D</s:item><s:item>E</s:item><s:item>F</s:item><s:item>G</s:item><s:item>H</s:item><s:item>I</s:item><s:item>J</s:item><s:item>K</s:item><s:item>L</s:item><s:item>M</s:item><s:item>N</s:item><s:item>O</s:item></s:list></s:key>
        <s:key name="group_id">MAC</s:key>
        <s:key name="label">NOT FOR RESALE</s:key>
        <s:key name="max_violations">5</s:key>
        <s:key name="quota">1000000000</s:key>
        <s:key name="relative_expiration_interval">0</s:key>
        <s:key name="relative_expiration_start">0</s:key>
        <s:key name="sourcetypes"><s:list/></s:key>
        <s:key name="stack_id">mac</s:key>
        <s:key name="status">VALID</s:key>
        <s:key name="type">mac</s:key>
        <s:key name="window_period">30</s:key>
      </s:dict>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    -----------
  </entry>
  <entry>
    ----------
  </entry>
  <entry>
    ---------
  </entry>
</feed>
```

I am interested only in the field 1000000000

I browsed the stackoverflow for similar questions on xml parsing and then i also searched in google, i did not find any solution.

I read python docs -- [http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.XML]

and tried to frame some logic using the functions findall(), iterfind() ... Nothing seems to work.

How to extract quota field from the above atom feed (xml).

Please note, i tried ElementTree's parse function, i got an error. I can not use that function. I get the response from restAPI as feed. I am allowed to save it as file and then parse it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I can not use ElementTree's parse function. This is not a file on disk for me. This is response from restAPI. I am not allowed to save it as file and the parse the feed.

Answer (score 0):

```
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector

xml = \
"""
    <content type="text/xml">
      <s:dict>
        <s:key name="group_id">MAC</s:key>
        <s:key name="label">NOT FOR RESALE</s:key>
        <s:key name="max_violations">5</s:key>
        <s:key name="quota">1000000000</s:key>
        <s:key name="relative_expiration_interval">0</s:key>
        <s:key name="relative_expiration_start">0</s:key>
        <s:key name="sourcetypes"><s:list/></s:key>
        <s:key name="stack_id">mac</s:key>
        <s:key name="status">VALID</s:key>
        <s:key name="type">mac</s:key>
        <s:key name="window_period">30</s:key>
      </s:dict>
    </content>
"""

xxs = XmlXPathSelector(text=xml)
quota = xxs.select('//*[@name="quota"]/text()').extract()[0]
print quota
```